# Automator Variable in shell script

Tags: macos, shell, unix, automator

Is it possible to pass an Automator variable into a shell script?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To complement [@Ned Deily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664089/45375):

(Written as of OS X 10.9.2, still current as of OSX 10.10)

It is **often *not* necessary to create and use *explicit* variables** in Automator (using the `Set Value of Variable` and `Get Value of Variable` actions).

The previous action's output is automatically passed to a `Run Shell Script` action.

By default, the data is passed via *stdin*, however.

If you want it passed as *arguments* (`$1`, `$2`, ... - also accessible as an array via `$@`) instead, select `as arguments` from the `Pass input:` list on the right, as illustrated here:

[image]

In this example, the selected `Finder` items are passed as *POSIX-style paths* to the shell script.

---

That said, having a shell script process the data via *stdin* (using `read -r` in a loop)  works, too:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

1. Drag & drop
2. Store path in `filename` variable
3. Prompt window for input value in next variable
4. **get** `filename` variable
5. Store prompt value in `rename_to`
6. $1 – `rename_to` value, $2 – `filename` value

[image]